# How to conditionally add local variables in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have terraform code as below:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    newrelic = {
      source  = "newrelic/newrelic"
      version = "~> 3.11.0"
    }
  }
}

locals {
  severity_ranges = {
    increase : [[50]]
    decrease : [
      [-100, -50],
      [-49, -30],
      [-29, -15],
      [-14, -5]
    ]
  }[var.query_type]
  nrql_query = {
    decrease: {
      for id, val in var.severities:
      id => "${var.query} and events_count >= ${local.severity_ranges[id][0]} and events_count <= ${local.severity_ranges[id][1]}"
    }
    increase: {
      for id, val in var.severities:
      id => "${var.query} and user_count >= ${local.severity_ranges[id][0]}"

    }
  }
  nrql_threshold = {
    decrease: {
      for id, value in local.severity_ranges:
      id => value[1]
  }
    increase: {
      for id, value in local.severity_ranges:
      id => value[0]
    }
  }
}
```

I am using it inside modules as below:

```
module "data_increase" {
  source             = "./data"
  severities         = [4]
  query_type         = "increase"
  query              = "SELECT min(user_count) from table WHERE source='foo' and eventName='bar'"
}
```

When I generate the plan all the local variables are genrated when the query_type is `increase`. I want to generate severity_ranges, nrql_query, nrql_threshold only for `increase` when query_type is specified as `increase` and same with query_type `decrease`. Any ideas how we can achieve it in terraform.

One option I think is to give severity_ranges and nrql_threshold as input in the child module but I dont know how can I dynamically create query and give that as input.Any suggestions in this regard will be be appreciated thanks.

Comment: I can't run your code. Can you post how `var.query_type`looks like? Also your module usage doesn't use any local vars.